# Login for company web job application form

Tags: login

My stakeholder just informed me that they want to require the user login to our company web if they want to apply via eForm.

For me, I thought it would make users not want to apply if they have to sign up to this company app, but I need another reason to make my stakeholder believe me.

Do you have any suggestion? Do you have any web reference with this kind of request?

Comment: May I know company is corporate one or based on any product

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The company wants users to sign in to their website before they can download their app? Are the users company employees? Is downloading the app a requirement? Or is it a public app and users will have to go to the company's site before using it?

Comment: Clearly requiring registering for a login account will reduce the number of non-registered users submitting the eForm. The question is, is that the intention.

Comment: By "apply via eForm" do you mean apply for a job at the company?

Answer (score 1):

### Many users will not cross such a login wall

Absolutely, a login wall will cause many users to stop the process and not apply. This is well researched and documented:

Nielson Norman says [Login Walls Stop Users in Their Tracks](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/login-walls/).

[Medium.com](https://medium.com/@rameshdot0/the-death-of-the-login-b274b22e27a9#.vgrskwux9) says:

> The login wall is one of the most hated UX elements in the history of web/mobile development. This leads to huge drop off rates when users are presented with the login wall.

And [UX planet](https://uxplanet.org/8-mobile-ux-mistakes-you-re-probably-making-right-now-cbc4f150e674#.kw8108n5r) says:

> Users almost always annoyed than when they come across a login wall. Because demanding that users must register or log in before they can use an app or see website information has high interaction cost.

### Does a login wall serve a purpose for your company?

It may be, however, that your company is willing (or happy) to have such an obstacle in their application process. This may be the case if:

1. The company is receiving too many applications
2. Many of the applicants are ultimately not interested in the job

If these are true, a login wall be a cheap way for the company to have the applicants self-select: only the more motivated applicants will go through the more difficult process to apply.

#### Don’t expect highly desirable employees to jump through hoops like a login wall

Sought-after employees know they don’t need to deal with difficult corporate application procedures, if they don’t wish to. A login wall will help your company select for the *most motivated* job seekers, not the *most qualified* ones.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the purpose of the eForm is.

If it's used to obtain information about a product or service, most adults will walk away because having to register is costly in terms of time and possible exposure to spammers, but there may be no payoff for that work.

Adults generally do not want to do something that benefits a corporation without getting something at least equally valuable in return.  Information about a company's product or service is not equally valuable unless that company is the only source for that kind of product or service.

If it's the application form for a job, the more-qualified applicants will walk away and only the less-qualified applicants will do the work.  The less-qualified are willing to do it because they are more desperate for a job than those with greater qualifications.

If you do a search on "adult motivation" or "adult vs child motivation" you will get many references to why adults are motivated to learn. Learning is a good model for work in general: it's hard, takes time, and exposes the learner to the possibility of failure.

Adults are goal-oriented, and they won't do things speculatively.  Adults need to know that there is a payoff for the work they do, whether the work is learning, or listening to a sales pitch, or registering before being allowed to fill up a form.  No payoff?  No willingness.